# How to embed zoom video on a moodle website?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api, zoom-sdk

I wanted to embed a stream of a Zoom meeting into HTML and allow users to attend meetings directly inside of an application. I used the following code.

```
<div class="iframe-container" style="overflow: hidden; padding-top: 56.25%; position: relative;">
        <iframe allow="microphone; camera" style="border: 0; height: 100%; left: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%;" src="https://success.zoom.us/wc/join/{meeting-id}" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

It worked succcessfully in a basic php site.

**Is it possible to apply the same to a moodle website...?**

There is a moodle plugin "**Zoom Video**", but it does not provide this functionality.

How can I add a separate code to embed zoom video on a moodle website...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add an HTML page from Moodle activity and put your HTML code in it.

Comment: Yes. That is the correct way. First select "Add an activity or resource" of a course. Then choose "Page" option. Then you will go to "edit settings" of that page. Then under "Content", you have to choose "show/hide advanced buttons". Select the "HTML" option. Their you can add any html code.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Zoom embed code generator on https://www.fullstacksys.com/zoom-embed-code-generator that generates Zoom embed code from Zoom SDK and I can use it for my website however it doesn't support mobile yet.